# Cloudfront suddenly slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

We are a B2B company and one of our clients customers is facing very slow download speeds from our cloudfront distribution for the 6-7 days. Earlier it was working fine. Our client provides learning videos which his customer is not able to stream at all (speeds < 4-5 kbps). The internet connection is good as all other video sites are working smooth and even cloudfront was smooth earlier. 2-3 other customers have also been complaining about sudden slowness.

Comment: I am facing same issue with ISP, it works fine with Wifi. You find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I will advice you to try following steps to debug to understand where the real problem is:

1. accessing the video directly viz. using S3 bucket and not via CloudFront. Response with CloudFront should be faster as compared to accessing directly.
2. Note that Cloudfront is faster when u acccess same video second time. First time it will be slower.
3. Try accessing via CF from different IP Address and if possible from different Data provider. Might be you can try using your Mobile connection.. sometimes, it is the problem of connectivity between that particular data provider and CF.

Comment: With regards to the mentioned points -
1. I will try once with S3 but reason for us not doing that is because we don't want to make the data public.

2. The videos were running fine last week and have suddenly slowed down so running second time probably is not the issue.

3. The problem here is the client only has one service provider with them. Yes it is a mobile connection but as I said she was accessing last week using same settings and it worked fine. How do we sort the issue of connectivity b/w data provider and CF.

Comment: Tried serving with s3 directly and it works perfect. Seems to be a connection issue with ISP and CF. How do we debug that?

Comment: ISPs use all kinds of tricks to `rate limit` customers. There is not much that you can do.

Comment: @JohnHanley that's sad if that's the case. Also why is not happening on Youtube. Also as now I have moved these clients to S3, will the ISP's rate limit S3 servers too?

Comment: I don't have a magic crystal ball to see what methods the ISP is using to rate limit customers. YouTube, Netflix, etc. have made deals with the ISPs. Google search this issue to see the politics.

Comment: these steps are just to debug the issue.. not for production.. so u can always make data public on S3 and try.. I do understand that client has only one data connection etc.. but we are just trying to debug

Comment: also, as u said that direct with S3 works fine; then it is also possible that someone changed some thing on your CF configuration..which is why it stopped working ; though this really looks very remote.. because whatever worst configuration u do on CF; it should still be better than accessing S3 directly .. hehe

Comment: @Deepak nothing was changed on the CF configuration from our end (not sure if AWS does it by themselves). Yes CF should be better that S3 but sadly currently something else is the case. We are serving through S3 for now, hope to get a solution soon.

Comment: +1 for mentioning 4g data providers. They have trouble accessing cloudfront caching for some odd reason. Maybe the locality from where it's being accessed also could be a reason.

Comment: Does anyone find any solution for this? I face the same issue with ISP however it is working fine with Wifi.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh probably give few days and that ISP would resolve issue on its own. best you can do is report the issue to ISP.

Comment: I am facing this issue with all ISP in Mumbai Vodafone-Idea, Airtel, Jio however it works fine with Wifi. What should I do?